# Replace Word Number string with Word_Number

Tags: python, regex

I am using Regex in Python to substitute `Word Number` pairs to the following form `Word_Number`.

For example:

```
import re
text = 'Opera 20 Opera 19 Version Hello World'.lower()
text = re.sub(r'(\[a-z]+)( )(\d)', r'\1_\2', text)
# text = re.sub(r'\([a-z]+)(.*)(\d+)', r'\1_\2', text)
print(text)
```

Expected Output:

```
opera_20 opera_19 version hello world
```

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you are after

```
text = re.sub(r'([a-z]+)( )(\d+)', r'\1_\3', text)
```

The changes were

1. No escape of `[` required
2. `\d` needs to be repeated
3. Capture group replacement needs to be `\3` not `\2`

You could drop the capture group for the empty space as well

```
re.sub(r'([a-z]+)\s+(\d+)', r'\1_\2', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b\s(\d+)
```